# Cyclic cubic extensions and Kummer theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, kummer-theory

The Galois cohomology group $H^1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ classifies cyclic cubic extensions $K/\mathbb{Q}$ (specifically: the non-trivial elements correspond to Galois cubic field extensions $K/\mathbb{Q}$ together with a choice of isomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$).

Let $k = \mathbb{Q}(\mu_3)$. There are restriction and corestriction maps
$$\mathrm{Res}: H^1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(k, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}), \quad \mathrm{Cores}: H^1(k, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}).$$ 
Restriction followed by corestriction is multiplication by $2$ on $H^1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$. As each element is $3$-torsion, it follows that $\mathrm{Res}$ is injective and that $\mathrm{Cores}$ is surjective.

But as $\mu_3 \subset k$, it follows from Kummer theory that 
$$H^1(k, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^1(k, \mu_3) \cong k^*/k^{*3}.$$
Composing with corestriction, we therefore obtain a surjective map
$$f: k^{*}/k^{*3} \to H^1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}).$$

> > Can the map $f$ be made explicit? Namely, given a non-cube $a \in k^*$, what is the cyclic cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ induced by $f$?

I know that the corestriction $H^1(k, \mu_3) \cong k^*/k^{3*} \to \mathbb{Q}^*/\mathbb{Q}^{*3} \cong H^1(\mathbb{Q}, \mu_3)$ is just usual norm map. But this doesn't seem to help here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just the map

$$x \mapsto y = \frac{x}{x^{\sigma}},$$

where the corresponding degree three extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the degree three subfield of $k(y^{1/3})$. The point is that it is obvious from the restriction map that

$$H^1(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z})
= (k^{\times}/k^{\times 3})^{G = {\chi}},$$

where $\chi$ is the non-trivial character of $G = \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$.

(**Added** Here $M^{\chi}$ means what is says on the tin. If $\sigma \in G$ and $m \in M^{\chi}$, then $\sigma m = \chi(\sigma) m$.)

And basic Kummer theory also says that degree 3 cyclic extensions $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ have the form $K(\zeta_3) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)(\alpha^{1/3})$ where

$$\sigma \alpha = \alpha^{-1} \mod k^{\times}/k^{\times 3}.$$

The same basic structure holds *mutatis mutandis* with $\mathbb{Q}$ replaced by any number field $F$, and $3$ replaced by $p$, and $G = \chi$ where now $\chi$ is the mod-p cyclotomic character of $G = \mathrm{Gal}(F(\zeta_p)/F)$, which is the canonical (possibly trivial) map $G \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. And now the map from $k^{\times}/k^{\times p}$ is just the projection to the $\chi$-eigenspace.

**Added**: If you want an explicit polynomial, you can, of course, use Galois theory to do so. In fact, everything in this question one can (and I do) teach in the introductory undergraduate Galois theory course. To spell out the elementary details, you want an element of $k(y^{1/3})$ which is fixed by the order two element $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(k(y^{1/3})/\mathbb{Q})$ (there is an obvious splitting from $\mathrm{Gal}(k/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(k(y^{1/3}/\mathbb{Q})$). The obvious element to take is thus

$$z = y^{1/3} + \sigma y^{1/3} = y^{1/3} + y^{-1/3},$$

which is a root of

$$T^3 - 3 T - (y + y^{-1}) = T^3 - 3 T - \left(\frac{x}{x^{\sigma}} + \frac{x^{\sigma}}{x}\right) 
= T^3 - 3 T - \frac{Tr(x^2)}{N(x)} \in \mathbb{Q}[T].$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which I'm currently trying to digest. Can you please clarify what you mean by the notation $(k^*/k^{*3})^{G = \chi}$? Do you mean the set of elements which are invariant under the action of the Galois group $G$? If so, why is this those elements $\alpha$ with $\sigma \alpha \equiv \alpha^{-1} \bmod k^{*3}$, and not $\sigma \alpha \equiv \alpha \bmod k^{*3}$? (I assume that $\sigma$ denotes the non-trivial element of $G$?).

Comment: I was also hoping for an explicit polynomial of degree $3$ which defines the cyclic cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Does your method give this?

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. You have defined what $M^{\chi}$ is, but I still don't understand what the notation $M^{G = \chi}$ means. Normally $M^G$ denotes the $G$-invariants for a module with $G$ action, but it seems that you mean something else.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate the answer, I don't think I can accept it until the notation is clarified and also it is clarified why $\alpha^{-1}$ appears, rather than $\alpha$.

Comment: Inflation-Restriction on cohomology (look it up) gives an isomorphism $H^1(\mathbf{Q},\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}) = H^1(k,\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z})^G$ where $G = \mathrm{Gal}(k/\mathbf{Q})$. As $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/k)$-modules, $\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z} = \mu_3$, so $H^1(k,\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z}) = H^1(k,\mu_3)$.

Comment: But this isomorphism doesn't respect the $G$-action --- $G$ acts on $\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z}$ by the trivial character, and on $\mu_3$ by the character $\chi$, which is also equal to $\chi^{-1}$. Hence $H^1(k,\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z})^{G} = H^1(k,\mu_3)^{\chi}$.

Comment: I think I see where my confusion lies: the point is that the action of $G$ on $k^*/k^{*3}$ is not the one induced from the action of $G$ on $k^*$, but rather $G$ acts on $k^*/k^{*3}$ via $(\sigma,\alpha) \mapsto 1/\alpha^{\sigma}$ (where $\alpha^{\sigma}$ denotes the usual action of $G$ on $k^*$). Is this correct?

Comment: Your comment is ambiguous, but assuming you mean: The action of the non-trivial $\sigma \in G$ on $k^{\times}/k^{\times 3}$ <i>induced from the isomorphism</i> $H^1(k,\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z}) \simeq k^{\times}/k^{\times 3}$ is via the map $\alpha \mapsto \chi(\sigma)(\alpha^{\sigma}) = (\alpha^{\sigma})^{-1} \mod k^{\times 3}$, then yes, that is correct. Also, I wouldn't use this notation, but from the context $M^{G = \chi}$ means the elements of $M$ where "$G$ acts by $\chi$" which is also just $M^{\chi}$.

Comment: @Margerie Mumblecrust: Thanks again for the answer. BTW, I would love to know which University you work at, which teaches Galois cohomology and Kummer theory in an introductory undergraduate Galois theory course!

Comment: Let $\sigma \alpha = \beta$. If $k(\alpha^{1/3})$ is Galois over $\mathbf{Q}$, then $k(\alpha^{1/3}) = k(\beta^{1/3})$ thus $\beta = \alpha$ or $\alpha^{-1} \mod k^{*3}$. So $\beta = \alpha x^3$ or $\alpha^{-1} x^3$ with $x \in k^*$. In case 1 the order $2$ element (sending $\alpha$ to $\beta$ and $\zeta_3$ to $\zeta^2_3$) does not commute with the order $3$ element (sending $\alpha^{1/3}$ to $\zeta_3 \alpha^{1/3}$ and fixing $\zeta_3$), and in case 2 it does. So abelian extensions are given by $k(\alpha^{1/3})$ with $\alpha \in k^{*}/k^{*3}$ where $\sigma \alpha = \alpha^{-1}$ in this group.

Comment: @DanielLoughran Going from the name, she probably teaches at Hogwarts. And Pound Sterling must be the reincarnation of quid.

Comment: BTW: I think the stated equation $H^1(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z})
= (k^{\times}/k^{\times 3})^{G = {\chi}}$ is not correct. Either the first term should be $H^1(k,\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z})$, or in the second term one should take $G$-invariants. This, compounded with the non-standard notation, added a lot to my initial confusion.

Comment: Given that (as agreed in the comments) the only possible interpretation of the notation $M^{G = \chi}$ is to mean $\{m \ | \  m \in M, gm = \chi(m)g\}$, then not only is $H^1(\mathbf{Q},\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}) = (k^{\times}/k^{\times 3})^{G = \chi}$ correct, it is absolutely the entire point,  and if you don't understand that then you don't understand the answer.