# Connecting different ways of constructing cubic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, computational-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

There are at least two ways to construct cyclic cubic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ as explained below. (A third one is given in the [answer to an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/310805/124862)).

1. Given $A, B, C$ integers with $A\neq 0$ we put
   $$
         \lambda=-\frac{C^2+27B^2}{4A^3}
      $$
   Then, if $(a,b,c)=\lambda(A,B,C)$, we see that $c^2=-4a^3-27b^2$. Hence, the discriminant of $T^3+aT+b$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$. So the simple extension $\mathbb{Q}[z]$ obtained by adjoining a root $z$ of this polynomial is normal and cyclic. (Assume that $A$ and $B$ are chosen so that this polynomial is irreducible which is not difficult.)
2. Given a positive integer $k$ such that $3$ divides the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/(k))^{*}$, there is a subgroup $H$ of this group that has index $3$. Choosing one such $H$, we see that if $E=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_k]$, then $F=E^{H}$ is a cyclic cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

According to the [Kronecker-Weber Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem), every construction in (1) is associated with *some* construction in (2).

**Question**: Given $a$ and $b$, is there an algorithm to determine $k$? (The [link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/310805/124862) referenced above can perhaps be used to determine an $a$ and $b$ given $H$.)

To begin with even a "brute force" algorithm based on giving a bound on $k$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ would be nice.

A specific case (which motivated this question) is when $(a,b)=(-7,-7)$. Then, serendipity led one to the solution $k=7$. This pair $(a,b)$ is different from the one produced by the referenced link. (Of course, multiple $(a,b)$ pairs could give the same extension.)

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Some key ideas for an answer are in an [answer to a related question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31600/596993).

Answer (score 4):

This is very well known: see for instance Theorem 6.4.6 in my book GTM 138.

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit embarrasing since I even once taught some material from this book. Clearly, I didn't get far enough!

Comment: The suggested text gives a canonical form for cyclic cubic fields. Hence, given $(a,b)$ one could compute the canonical form. This should lead to a bound on $k$ and then one can try various $H$'s.

Comment: After reading GTM 138 and the proof of Lemma 6.4.5, one can see that given $(a,b)$ one can compute the canonical form for the cubic equation. So, further using Theorem 6.4.6 I can see how one can decide exactly which of the cases occur. However, I still could not see a way to bound $k$ given that the cubic field is written in this canonical form.